# Implementing map entry listener

Tags: scala, akka, listener

I'm trying to implement Map entry listener with Scala.

Idea:

1. I need to subscribe to the Map from Service.
2. I need to notify all subscribers of the Map when entry with specific key is added/updated.
3. I need to have access to the Map from other Services to check entry value.

I couldn't find ready solution for this, so I've tried to implement it with Akka:

```
class TrackingService(system: ActorSystem) extends LazyLogging {
  private val trackingActor = system.actorOf(TrackingActor.props)
  private val duration = Duration(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  private implicit val timeout = Timeout(duration)

  def fireEvent(key: String): Unit = {
    TrackingActor ! EventFired(key)
  }

  def eventHappened(key: String): Future[Boolean] = {
    TrackingActor ? DoesEventHappened(key)).mapTo[Boolean]
  }

  def registerHiddenCardListener(key: String, data: MyData): Unit = {
    TrackingActor ! Subscribe(key, data)
  }
}

case class EventFired(key: String)
case class EventHappened(key: String)
case class EventHappenedResponse(happened: Boolean)

case class Subscribe(key: String, data: Data)
class TrackingActor extends Actor with LazyLogging {
  var eventMap: Map[String, Boolean] = Map.empty[String, Boolean]
  var dataMap: Map[String, List[Data]] = Map.empty[String, List[Data]]

  def receive: Receive = {
    case Subscribe(key, data)       =>
      val currentData: List[Data] = dataMap.getOrElse(key, Nil)
      val newData = data :: currentData
      dataMap = dataMap + (key -> newData)
    case EventHappened(key)         => sender() ! EventHappenedResponse(eventMap.getOrElse(key, false))
    case e@EventFired(key)          =>
      eventMap = eventMap + (key -> true)

      for {
        dataOpt <- dataMap.get(key)
        data <- dataOpt
      } {
        // do callback with data (e.g. send email)
      }
    case x => logger.warn(s"Received unknown message: $x")
  }
}

object TrackingActor {
  def props: Props = Props(classOf[TrackingActor])
}
```

What I don't like in this solution: I don't like ask pattern, but I need to have access to the entries from non-actor classes. Also, I don't like having 2 maps, but I need to store somewhere data, which should be used for the callback.

Any ideas on how can I improve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

```
case class Subscribe[A, B](f: (A, B, NotifyingMap[A,B]) => Any)

case class Event[A, B](key: A, value: B, originator: NotifyingMap[A,B])

case class RegisterObserver(actorRef: ActorRef)

/**
  * Subscribes to events
  */
class Subscriber[A,B]{

  def register(actorSystem: ActorSystem) = {
    val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(classOf[Observer[A,B]]))
    actor ! Subscribe(handleEvent)
  }

  def handleEvent(key: A, value: B, notifyingMap: NotifyingMap[A, B]) = {
    println(s"Saw key $key with value $value")
  }
}

/**
  * Observer of events that will call a partial function when
  * an event comes in.
  */
class Observer[A, B] extends Actor{
  var f: (A,B,NotifyingMap[A,B]) => Any = _

  def receive = {
    case x: Subscribe[A, B] =>
      f = x.f
      Notifier() ! RegisterObserver(self)
    case e: Event[A,B] =>
      f(e.key, e.value, e.originator)
  }
}

/**
  * Notifier that sends out the event to all registered observers.
  */
class Notifier extends Actor {
  var observers = List[ActorRef]()

  def receive = {
    case x: RegisterObserver =>
      observers = x.actorRef :: observers
    case x: Event[_,_] =>
      observers.foreach(_ ! Event)
  }
}

/**
  * Singleton notifier.
  */
object Notifier{

  var notifier: ActorRef = _

  def create(actorSystem: ActorSystem) =
    actorSystem.actorOf(Props(classOf[Notifier]))

  def apply(): ActorRef =  notifier
}

/**
  * Class that sends out an event when an item is put. Also allows for
  * getting an item based on a key.
  */
class NotifyingMap[A, B](){
  val map: TrieMap[A,B] = TrieMap[A,B]()

  // Specific business logic here on when you publish the event.
  def put(key: A, value: B) = {
    map.put(key, value).foreach(v => Notifier() ! Event(key, v, this))
  }

  def get(key: A) = map.get(key)
}
```

By doing this you can keep your Subscriber a non-`Actor` class while still allowing it to react to an event. You can also call plain old methods on your `NotifyingMap` since it's just a class and not an `Actor`.

I personally like to store callback information in the messages. Typically you see this by having another `ActorRef` in a case class. In this example we have the `NotifyingMap` in the case class so we know where the event originated from and can appropriately call the `get` method there.

Full disclosure: I didn't run any of this code. It does compile.